# How do I call a method from hovering in FXML?

Tags: javafx, hover, fxml

I am working on a program, in which I need to paint two images red when I hover over a button which connects them. The thing is that I need to do this while its HOVERING, not when the user clicks the button.
I am using FXML with css for styling, but I dont see any way to call a method from the :hover of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you can do

```
private final PseudoClass highlightImage = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight");

@FXML
private Node someNode1 ;
@FXML
private Node someNode2 ;
@FXML
private Button button ;

public void initialize() {
    button.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
        someNode1.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightImage, isNowHovered);
        someNode2.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightImage, isNowHovered);
    });
}
```

Then in the CSS you can do

```css
#someNode1, #someNode2 {
    // regular styles
}

#someNode1:highlight, #someNode2:highlight {
    // hover styles
}
```

---

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class HighlightOnHoverController {

    @FXML
    private Rectangle leftRect ;
    @FXML
    private Rectangle rightRect ;
    @FXML
    private Button button ;

    private final PseudoClass highlightRect = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlight");

    public void initialize() {
        button.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHovered, isNowHovered) -> {
            leftRect.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightRect, isNowHovered);
            rightRect.pseudoClassStateChanged(highlightRect, isNowHovered);
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void click() {
        System.out.println("Button clicked");
    }
}
```

HighlightOnHover.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HighlightOnHoverController" spacing="20" alignment="CENTER">
     <padding>
        <Insets top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" />
     </padding>
     <Rectangle fx:id="leftRect" styleClass="rect" width="50" height="50" />
     <Button fx:id="button" text="Click Me" onAction="#click" />
     <Rectangle fx:id="rightRect" styleClass="rect" width="50" height="50" />
</HBox>
```

highlight-on-hover.css:

```css
.rect {
    -fx-fill: cornflowerblue ;
}
.rect:highlight {
    -fx-fill: coral ;
}
```

HighlightOnHover.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightOnHover extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HighlightOnHover.fxml")));
        scene.getStylesheets().add("highlight-on-hover.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Not hovering on the button:

[image]

Hovering on the button:

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly! It will take somo work to adapt it to my program but thats up to me! You have my gratitude.